# Selenium test Java maven dependencies

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I created tests on selenium ide. I want to run java files on intellij idea. I prepared pom.xml like that but I have problem with running tests.

```
dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.33.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

When I run it, tests are failed

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706) on port 28288
Only local connections are allowed.
paź 22, 2019 3:17:24 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".ion-navicon"}
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.15.0-65-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

What should I do to run it on Intellij Idea?

Comment: Adding  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  before locators resolve problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use same selenium version for selenium-java, selenium-server etc.
It will help you to prevent from any unexpected error

Change below dependencies to the latest version as per today it is `4.1.3`. You can find the latest versions in this URL:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Another thing you are getting error as below:

> no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":".ion-navicon"}   (Session info:
> chrome=76.0.3809.132)

That means your locator is not correct or it is not ready. check your locator and add wait also before the element to locate

Comment: Thanks, add driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); resolve it.

Comment: The newest version can be found here: [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java)